# Convert one dimension list to two diminsions with specific delimiters

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, delimiter

I have a list like:

```
['A;B;C;D\nE;F;G;H\nI;J;K;L\n']
```

I want to create a new list which hold data in two dimensions like :

```
[[A,B,C,D],[E,F,G,H],[I,J,K,L]]
```

How can I make the ";" as the delimiter and "\n" to enter data into new row?

Thanks.

(I am using python v3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `listcomprehension` with with `str.split()` and `str.strip()`

```
a = ['A;B;C;D\nE;F;G;H\nI;J;K;L\n']
In [152]: [x.split(';') for x in a[0].strip().split('\n')]
Out[152]: [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'], ['I', 'J', 'K', 'L']]
```

or use `map` with `lambda` function

```
In [160]: map(lambda x: x.split(';') ,a[0].strip().split('\n'))
Out[160]: [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'], ['I', 'J', 'K', 'L']]
```

In both time difference is small

```
In [162]: %timeit map(lambda x: x.split(';') ,a[0].strip().split('\n'))
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.04 µs per loop

In [161]: %timeit [x.split(';') for x in a[0].strip().split('\n')]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.46 µs per loop
```